# CKAN DataStore - Set permissions

Tags: ckan

(I am not an IT guy, so some of my doubts may seem pretty basic / strange)

Through this tutorial (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.0-on-CentOS-7) I was able to install CKAN.

After, I understood that I would need the DataStore extension for the preview function work well on my installation.
Using the documentation I get staked in Set Permissions step (http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/datastore.html#set-permissions), in something that  I can not understand

I make

```
 paster datastore set-permissions postgres -c /etc/ckan/default/development.ini
```

and it ask  me for the ckan password

```
WARNI [ckanext.datastore.plugin] Omitting permission checks because you are running paster commands.
[sudo] password for ckan:
```

but witch password?

when installing CKAN I had to create a ckan user by doing:

```
useradd -m -s /sbin/nologin -d /usr/lib/ckan -c "CKAN User" ckan
```

but I haven't define any password

If I just give "enter" and won't accept
I tried also to give the password of the sysadmin I created for the Ckan site and also don't work

I really like some help to known what I should do with this.

thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you may be running your *virtualenv* as *user:* `ckan` - which probably won't have the required permissions.

If you are, return back to *user:* `root` by **typing exit or pressing Ctrl + D**.

If you did a source install, make sure to have your *virtualenv* activated as `root` and then run the paster command again from your CKAN source directory.

eg.

`. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan`

Comment: Mat,
It was exactly that !

Appreciate your help, it really means a lot to me (I struggled for 2 days with this "small" thing )

Comment: NB You should not *normally* run as root. It is just the 'set-permissions' command that uses sudo, and because the Centos CKAN install does not set-up a sudo password, you need to run that single command as root. (In case anyone reads this answer and is misled into thinking you should always 'run the virtualenv as user: ckan')

Answer (score 1):

I've added a note about this https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.x-on-CentOS-7 to avoid other people falling into this trap

Comment: well done

It  was useful if that info could be added to the official CKAN DataStore documentation

Comment: The info is only relevant to the CentOS install of DataStore