# CKAN datapusher - which installation

Tags: ckan

I had install CKAN through this tutorial https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.0-on-CentOS-7

Following the installation of DataStore where I had this problem.([CKAN DataStore - Set permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271329/ckan-datastore-set-permissions))

In the folder `/usr/lib/ckan/default` I have the files:

```
bin  
include  
lib  
lib64  
man  
src
```

In the folder `/etc/ckan/default` I have the files:

```
apache.wsgi  
development.ini  
who.ini
```

Install: ckan-2.2.1 (installation from source); CentOS7

Which DataPusher do I install, the Production or Development installation?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question whit you at first. And then I have installed the DataPusher via the two ways. My system is ckan-2.5.2 (installation from source), and CentOS6.8. I can tell you my opinion about this question.

I think Development installation is a kind of software installation that you can use the datapusher for all the applications. And production installation is installing the datapusher as a plug-in module of CKAN. Although the Development installation is much more easier, I recommend you use the Production installation. Because I think there is an inconvenience to use datapusher after Development installation.  As the saying in [Doc of Development installation](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/development.html), you must run the datapusher via the following comment:

```
python datapusher/main.py deployment/datapusher_settings.py
```

You must do it at every time you want to use it. It is so inconvenient! I have wrote a guide about the production installation for CentOS on [Datapusher's wiki](https://github.com/ckan/datapusher/wiki). I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If, you are running CKAN on paster follow the developement installation.

If, you are deploying the CKAN with Apache web server(httpd for CentOS 7) follow the steps to deploy and follow the production install. Datapusher service should also be deployed.

Follow this link. It has datapusher installation for both developement and production installation (paster and Apache). And how to start datapsuher for respective servers

[Data Pusher Documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/)

If Developement instalation - you have to run the command

```
python datapusher/main.py deployment/datapusher_settings.py
```

If production Install you have to create the conf files and other wsgi files as mentioned in the link.